# Testcafe and allure reporter

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, allure, testcafe

I try to use the allure reporter found on

[Allure reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe-reporter-allure)

I created the runner:

```
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');
let testcafe         = null;

createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338)
    .then(tc => {
        testcafe     = tc;
        const runner = testcafe.createRunner();

        return runner
            .src(['tests/fixture1.js', 'tests/ingo1.js'])
            .browsers(['chrome'])
            .reporter('allure')
            .run();
    })
    .then(failedCount => {
        console.log('Tests failed: ' + failedCount);
        testcafe.close();
    });
```

When starting the script, I get the message "Allure reporter started" and when finished I get "Allure reporter finished". But In my root folder, I do not get any allure report. I also try to use my own config file

```
const DOC_ALLURE_CONFIG = {
    CLEAN_REPORT_DIR: true,
    COPY_HISTORY: true,
    RESULT_DIR: '/allure/allure-results',
    REPORT_DIR: '/allure/allure-report',
    META: {
        STORY_ID: 'STORY',
        TEST_ID: 'ID',
        SEVERITY: 'SEVERITY',
        TEST_RUN: 'TEST_RUN'
    },
    STORY_LABEL: 'JIRA Story Link',
    STORY_URL: 'https://jira.example.ca/browse/{{ID}}',
    TEST_LABEL: 'JIRA Test Link',
    TEST_URL: 'https://jira.example.ca/secure/Tests.jspa#/testCase/{{ID}}',
    labels: {
        screenshotLabel: 'Screenshot',
        browserLabel: 'Browser',
        userAgentLabel: 'User Agent',
        allureStartMessage: 'Allure Ingo reporter started...',
        allureClosedMessage: 'Allure Ingo reporter closed...'
    }
};

module.exports = DOC_ALLURE_CONFIG;
```

This also does not work. The custom messages are not shown, just the default.
It looks like the allure plugin ignores everything and o not recognize my node module well.

What setting did I miss to get the allure reports in my project root?

(Tried also to with an npm link...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestCafe does not officially support the `testcafe-reporter-allure` reporter, so we can only recommend you ask its author or the allure community about the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The testcafe-allure-reporter folder stores generated reports relative to the path where this module was installed. So, try to install testcafe-allure-reporter locally to your project and execute the script. After that, the allure/allure-results folder should appear in your project root directory.

Answer (score 0):

I used this more recent package instead and it works out of the box: https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe-reporter-allure-expanded